# Identify a chrome theme

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I uninstalled my chrome theme because some buttons were dark that shouldnt've been; planning to re-install it later

However, when I opened the theme browser I couldn't find it anywhere

Here's an image of what the address bar looked like
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOFzj.png)

I appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [James White](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/james-white/bkeidgmehkdjmpjodpjkepolokanalkm) Click the name to add the theme.